# Ubuntu XSANE has too many windows!

Tags: panel, scanner, canon, xsane

I installed XSANE because I couldn't get SimpleScan to work with my Canon MX490 printer. XSANE works OK (still trying to connect via wifi but USB works). But when I open XSANE and scan a document, I get 5 different windows. Now, I'm sure there are plenty of Folk that like all these windows but I find it a terrible way to work with the software. Is there a configuration setting that will combine them all together and give me just 1 tab / item (whatever you call them) in my Panel instead of 5?